# Build SQL queries in Python

Tags: python, sql

Are there any python packages that help generating SQL queries from variables and classes?

For example, instead of writing create query manually, the developer will create a create table (as an object maybe), with desired columns in a list for instance. Then the object will return a string that will be used as a query. It would be a plus if such package can support multiple language syntax (SQLite, Oracle, MySQL, ...)

Comment: user input such as?..  please provide some context on the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best Object-Relational mapper package for Python today is the popular [SqlAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

Answer (score 1):

The standard python MySQLdb package will do the right things about quoting variables if it's given a chance.  If you're worried about SQL injection attacks.

```
c.executemany(
      """INSERT INTO breakfast (name, spam, eggs, sausage, price)
      VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
      [
      ("Spam and Sausage Lover's Plate", 5, 1, 8, 7.95 ),
      ("Not So Much Spam Plate", 3, 2, 0, 3.95 ),
      ("Don't Wany ANY SPAM! Plate", 0, 4, 3, 5.95 )
      ] )
```

Otherwise you should probably be looking at any number of python web frameworks - Django, etc. to abstract the database.